# How to escape the At-sign (@) in Bash

Tags: command-line, unix, bash, shell

Since Apple made a requirement for certain file names to include an at-sign (`@`) in my iPhone application project, I can't check in my files using the Subversion commandline. How do is escape the `@`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use files with @ signs in Subversion, add an extra @ at the end of the filename.

```
svn add image@2x.png@
```